# Why does OpenLayers use several canvas elements for rendering when the pixel ratio is a fractional number?

Tags: javascript, canvas, maps, gis, openlayers

I am building a feature where we export an OpenLayers map as a PNG or JPEG image. To do this we grab the OpenLayers map's `canvas` element and convert it to BLOB.

I have noticed that while usually all the layers are rendered into a single canvas, sometimes OL uses several canvas elements:

[image]

Where I don't understand the logic is that the trigger seems to be when the device pixel-ratio is a fractional number. For example, pixel ratios of 1.0 and 2.0 result in a single canvas being used, but 1.2 or 1.5 result in several canvases.

It's not really a problem as I can just grab all the canvases and draw their content in a new one and so get the complete map. But I am curious to understand what the logic is behind this and if it is some kind of optimization.

Comment: Can you share an example page where you see this behavior? Trying a few from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/ I can't really see it happening on my machine.

Comment: What you are seeing there is a rounding issue which will be fixed in the next release https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/15344  However when the view is rotated it is common to see multiple canvases as some layer types rotate the canvas with the view while others do not.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, that seems to be the explanation, indeed. Do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?